# How to properly check whether header is sent along request or not

Tags: apache, logging, httpd.conf

I have a application that make request to a Restful API and should send along a parameter called `X-PDONE-SESSION-ID`. I need to check whether that header is sent along request or does not so I've enabled and configured as follow:

```
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
LoadModule log_forensic_module modules/mod_log_forensic.so
```

I have enabled VirtualHost so this is the config file for that VH:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName admin.domain.local
    ServerAlias api.domain.local
    ServerAlias share.domain.local

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/backend/web
    <Directory /var/www/html/backend/web>
        # enable the .htaccess rewrites
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog logs/pdone-error.log

    # CustomLog with format nickname
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t %r %{x-pdone-session-id}i %{Referer}i %{User-Agent}i %>s %b" common
    CustomLog logs/pdone-access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, the following lines should do the work:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t %r %{x-pdone-session-id}i %{Referer}i %{User-Agent}i %>s %b" common
CustomLog logs/pdone-access.log common
```

But this `%{x-pdone-session-id}i` is not logged on the log file, I have tried also by uppercase the value `%{X-PDONE-SESSION-ID}i` and didn't work neither. I got a log file like the one below:

```
192.168.3.1 - - [29/Jul/2015:10:22:19 -0430] "GET /app_dev.php/api/v1/reps/activity?_format=json&rid=00580000003AWtXAAW HTTP/1.1" 200 4369
```

I am making the request by using Postman Chrome extension and I am sending the header as image below shown, otherwise code fails with non authorized exception and code works, why I can't see that header on send headers? Why the value is not logged in? What I am missing here?

[image]

NOTE: if image is not shown good then right click over image and open in a new tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nickname `common` is usually defined in the main server config. Just don't give the nick name `common` to an other log format, but any other name that is not defined in the main server, and that will be unique:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t %r %{x-pdone-session-id}i %{Referer}i %{User-Agent}i %>s %b" pdone_common
```

I didn't know that before I've seen your question, but it is that nicknames defined in main server config cannot be overridden in VHost config.